# Site for feedback on FLOSS project?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Sorry if this has been posted already, I couldn't find exactly what I wanted.

I created a sitebuilder, and I'm looking for some feedback (in general, not the code). Where could I post?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: 'in general' as in its user experience? Or in terms of how it actually works?

Comment: I would say both. If the features are a good idea, looks good, looks like good UX, etc.

Comment: The all important question is; could you phrase your questions in such a way that it would be generally useful to other people?

Comment: Mh...FLOSS or closed?

Comment: The project is FLOSS, if I rephrased it "Site for feedback on FLOSS project"..? It would probably clarify that and make it useful to other at the same time.

Comment: If it is FLOSS; you could try to look for an appropriate subreddit on Reddit to post your request. I did not say that you should spam Reddit, but sometimes subreddits accept such posts (requests for beta testing or "adervisting" of FLOSS projects).

Comment: @nbrogi - Use [`@username`](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) to ping them like this. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no sites on the Stack Exchange for reviewing/testing applications, and I couldn't find such proposals on Area51.

But there are external websites for beta testing and reviewing:

- [Centercode](http://www.centercode.com/testers/)
- [TryBeta](http://www.trybeta.com/login/index.php)
- [uTest](http://www.utest.com/)
- [OnlineBeta](https://www.onlinebeta.com)

Answer (score 3):

If you would like feedback on a snippet of code, try [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com). Otherwise,  this type of question is rather localized (the answers won't be useful to the general audience), so not really appropriate for this network.

You can try asking in the relevant [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com) room, though.

---

Of course, you can ask about a specific design decision at [UX.SE](http://ux.stackexchange.com), as long as you can phrase it so that it's useful to others.

Comment: Yeah, I was looking at Code Review but (as the names says) it's just for code. Thanks for your help!